Can not access https service via istio-ingress
I am new in istio. I try to configure istio ingress in k8s. But I can't access service via istio-ingress.
How can I configure istio ingress for service.

Problem
# curl https://192.168.4.241
curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.4.241:443; Connection refused


My service is deployed as below.(smartapigw-httpd is HTTPS)

# kubectl get po smartapigw-httpd -n smartapigw --show-labels
NAME               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     LABELS
smartapigw-httpd   2/2     Running   0          3h22m   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,app=smartapigw-httpd,io.kompose.service=smartapigw-httpd,security.istio.io/tlsMode=istio,service.istio.io/canonical-name=smartapigw-httpd,service.istio.io/canonical-revision=latest

$ kubectl get po,svc -n smartapigw 
... 
pod/smartapigw-httpd          2/2     Running            0                166m 
...
service/smartapigw-httpd           NodePort    10.101.227.150   <none> 18443:31285/TCP   166m


istio-ingress pod is deployed as below

$ kubectl get po -n istio-system --show-labels
...
istio-ingressgateway-5ff4fb69fc-trmht   1/1     Running            0                 28h   app=istio-ingressgateway,chart=gateways,heritage=Tiller,install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource=unknown,istio.io/rev=default,istio=ingressgateway,operator.istio.io/component=IngressGateways,pod-template-hash=5ff4fb69fc,release=istio,service.istio.io/canonical-name=istio-ingressgateway,service.istio.io/canonical-revision=latest,sidecar.istio.io/inject=false
istiod-6d79fdc756-lr5zv
...


istio ingressgateway is deployed as below

$ kubectl get svc -n istio-system
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.110.145.103   192.168.4.241   15021:32010/TCP,80:31631/TCP,443:30495/TCP       28h

Then I tried configuration as below.

Configuration for Gateway

# cat istio-smartapigw-gateway.yml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: smartagigw-gateway
  namespace: smartapigw
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway  # istio=ingressgateway in istio-ingressgateway pod's label
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPs
hosts:
- "*"
tls:
  mode: PASSTHROUGH  # smartapigw-httpd service's protocol is already https

# kubectl apply -f istio-smartapigw-gateway.yml


Configuration for VirtualService

# cat istio-smartapigw-virtualservice.yml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: smartapigw
  namespace: smartapigw
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - smartagigw-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
       prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: smartapigw-httpd  # same with label "app=smartapigw-httpd" in pod
        port:
          number: 18443         # node port 

# kubectl apply -f istio-smartapigw-virtualservice.yml

istio gateway and virtual service is applied as below.
# kubectl get gateway -n smartapigw
NAME                 AGE
smartagigw-gateway   138m

# kubectl get virtualservice -n smartapigw
NAME         GATEWAYS                 HOSTS   AGE
smartapigw   ["smartagigw-gateway"]   ["*"]   131m


The error message "Failed connect to 192.168.4.241:443; connection refused" suggests that there might be an issue with the Network connectivity or service is running and accessible on the specified IP and port.

Thanks for reply. But I have another example namely ngnix service(HTTP protocol). It works fine. Command "curl http://192.168.4.241 " is reached to nginx service. Problem is happened pod service protocol is HTTPS.

I resolve issue based on https://preliminary.istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-sni-passthrough/
VirtualService definition was changed as below. VirtualService protocol should be changed tls instead of http.
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3

kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: smartapigw
  namespace: smartapigw
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - smartagigw-gateway
  tls:
  - match:
    - port: 443
      sniHosts:
      - "*"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: smartapigw-httpd.smartapigw.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 18443

